# Android Hide RelativeLayout Completely

Tags: java, android

I want to hide a relative layout completely. i have a view with several Layouts i use as buttons with an onClickListener. Now i want to display only those Buttons that i want because sometimes an Object doesnt have all Data. I tried to set visiblity to "4" wich should be "gone" but that didnt do the trick. there still is space reserved for this Layout.
What can i do about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set it to View.GONE which is 8 not 4

Answer (score 10):

```
RelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

to hide:

```
RelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

to show it again:

```
RelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```